# Sample python code provided by GCP - service variable undefined

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

The following sample code is provided by GCP to use the restAPI to list out group membership when you provide the group_id.  [Code sample can be found here.](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/how-to/query-memberships#python)  I can run the sample directly from [the URI given](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/reference/rest/v1/groups.memberships/getMembershipGraph), but when trying to run it from Python with the sample code provided.  My IDE intellisense says that **service** in the very last line is an undefined variable.  I can find nothing in GCP to indicate what library this might come from or what I should replace it with.

```
def search_transitive_memberships(service, parent, page_size):
  try:
    memberships = []
    next_page_token = ''
    while True:
      query_params = urlencode(
        {
          "page_size": page_size,
          "page_token": next_page_token
        }
      )
      request = service.groups().memberships().searchTransitiveMemberships(parent=parent)
      request.uri += "&" + query_params
      response = request.execute()

      if 'memberships' in response:
        memberships += response['memberships']

      if 'nextPageToken' in response:
        next_page_token = response['nextPageToken']
      else:
        next_page_token = ''

      if len(next_page_token) == 0:
        break;

    print(memberships)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# Return results with a page size of 50
search_transitive_memberships(service, 'groups/01234567abcdefg', 50) ## <- service undefined
```

Appreciate assistance in identifying what I need to add to have service recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it appears what is missing from the code samples provided by GCP are the steps to build and use a service object.

Documentation on that can be found here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/start.md#building-and-calling-a-service

So for my sample above the last line would actually be:

```
service = build('cloudidentity', 'v1')
search_transitive_memberships(service, 'groups/01234567abcdefg', 50)
service.close
```

After importing `build` from `googleapiclient.discovery`

Github link above also details how to provide oauth creds for it to work.